# Efficient row-wise comparisons between two dataframes

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I am comparing two dataframes in a row wise fashion.

For each row in `data`, I want to check if there is a matching row in `reference`.

For a match to be considered as true, some conditions must be fullfiled:

1. I want the same number of non-null values in both row (so that I don't end up with false positives from rows in data matching only a slice of a row in reference)
2. I want to avoid comparing NaN values, so only compare the portion of the row that contains the actual values (hence why the 1st condition must be true)
3. I want to allow some tolerance while doing the comparions (I'm using `np.isclose` to do so)
4. I want the code to be fast

When a match is found, I append the name of both row in a list.
If there's no match, I append the name of the row in data with "not found", in the same list as above. And finally I create a summary table to see which row correspond (or not) to what.

To give you a sense of the structure of my dataframes:

```
    name    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    col7    col8        
0     X       10     20      30      40      50      60      70      80 
1     X       20     30      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2     X       10     25      30      50      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3     X       20     25      30      50      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

- my dataframes have ~130 columns
- Most of the time, they will have between 2 and 20 numerical values, the rest will be NaNs.
- In each row the numerical values are sorted in ascending order at the beginning of the row, the NaNs are at the end.

I have a working code that uses 2 for-loops but it is rather slow when used on big dataframes (here I test the code on some 'sample' dataframes):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':['read 1','read 2','read 3','read 4'],
                  'start 1':[100,102,100,103],
                  'end 1':[198,504,500,200],
                  'start 2':[np.NaN,600,650,601],
                  'end 2':[np.NaN,699, 700,702],
                  'start 3':[np.NaN,800,800,np.NaN],
                  'end 3':[np.NaN,901, 900,np.NaN]}, 
                   columns=['name', 'start 1', 'end 1', 'start 2', 'end 2', 'start 3', 'end 3'], 
                   dtype='float64')


reference = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a-1','a-2','b-1','c-1'],
                  'start 1':[100,100,100,300],
                  'end 1':[200,200,500,400],
                  'start 2':[300,np.NaN,600,600],
                  'end 2':[400,np.NaN, 700,700],
                  'start 3':[np.NaN,np.NaN,800,np.NaN],
                  'end 3':[np.NaN,np.NaN, 900,np.NaN]}, 
                   columns=['name', 'start 1', 'end 1', 'start 2', 'end 2', 'start 3', 'end 3'], 
                   dtype='float64')



match = []
checklist = set()

for read in data.itertuples():

    ndata = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(read[2:]),axis=0)

    end = ndata+1 if ndata>2 and  read[1] not in checklist else 4

    for ref in reference.itertuples():

        nref = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(ref[2:]),axis=0)

        if np.isclose(read[2:end],ref[2:end], atol=5).all() == True and ndata == nref:
            match.append([read[1], ref[1]])
            checklist.add(read[1])
            break

    if read[1] not in checklist:
        match.append([read[1], "not found"])
        checklist.add(read[1])     

match_table = pd.DataFrame(match)


match_table:

    read name     reference
0     read 1         a-2
1     read 2         b-1
2     read 3      not found
3     read 4      not found
```

So I decided to try optimizing it by using vectorization.
Now I only use 1 for-loop and was able to vectorize the 3rd condition with np.isclose but didn't managed for the other conditions.

I can bypass it by allowing `equal_nan=True` but as most of my rows will be full of NaN values, I think I will gain some time if I don't have to do these comparisons.

Here's what I got so far:

```
count = []

for read in data.itertuples(index=False):

    idx = np.argwhere(np.isclose(read[1:], reference.iloc[:,1:], atol=5, equal_nan=True).all(axis=1) == True).flatten()

    if idx.size == 0:
        count.append([read[0], "not found"]) 
    else:
        idx = idx.item()
        count.append([read[0], reference['name'][idx]])

match = pd.DataFrame(count)
```

I tested it with a 400×130 `data` dataframes on a 25×130 `reference` dataframe and it performed 6 times faster than the 1st version but still took 1s to complete. But maybe there's not much room for improvement.

#### Questions:

- How can I vectorize the operation(s) that would take care of conditions 1 and 2, allowing to not perform the NaN comparisons ?
- Is it possible to get rid of the inner for-loop ? If Yes, would that allow to gain more speed ?

#### Bonus question:

Why did I have to change the index from `read[1]` to `read[0]` between the 1st and the 2nd version of my code to be able to select the `['name']` column ? Seems like in one version it is 0-based and in the other it is not, or something like that. But being new to python and learning on my own, I don't really understand what happened here..

Comment: are the start & end values all going to be integers or null?

Comment: @HaleemurAli Yes. Apart from the first column that contains a string for the name of the row, all the other columns are filled with float or null values (just as in the example of my dataframes structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops may be avoided through use of `df.apply`. `itertuples` is slow and should only be used when absolutely necessary.

```
# index-setting not technically required, but makes the 
# rest of the code simpler
data = data.set_index('name')
reference = reference.set_index('name')

# define a helper function to use with apply
# taking the same logic as you have used
def get_ref(x):
    m = np.isclose(x, reference.values, atol=5, equal_nan=True).all(axis=1)
    return reference.index[m].item() if m.any() else np.nan

out = data.apply(get_ref, axis=1).rename('reference').reset_index()
# Outputs:
     name reference
0  read 1       a-2
1  read 2       b-1
2  read 3       NaN
3  read 4       NaN
```

---

You can get an additional speed boost if you go down to the numpy layer & user `np.apply_along_axis`

```
pd.DataFrame({'read name': data.index,
              'reference': np.apply_along_axis(get_ref, 1, data.values)}
```

---

#### timings:

On my machine, with the sample data

- the numpy version takes ~920 microseconds
- the pandas apply verion takes ~1.35 milliseconds
- your optimized version takes ~2.20 milliseconds

Comment: Thanks ! It worked really well on the example I gave above. However, the first solution with `df.apply()` works perfectly on my real dataframes but the second solution with `np.apply_along_axis()` give me the error: `"could not convert string to float"`. Any idea where it can come from ? The only "string" is in the first column that is set as index with the first lines of codes..

Comment: EDIT: it appears this is due to my strings having `.` in them. When creating the dataframe at the end, it apparently tries to convert the string to floats, hence the error.

Comment: replacing `np.NaN` with `"not found"` fixed the issue.